# How to use regex over entire dataframe in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, stringr

new user to R so please go easy on me.

I have dataframe like:

```
   df = data.frame(Mineral = c("Zfeldspar", "Zgranite", "ZSilica"),
                     Confidence = c("ZLow", "High", "Med"),
                     Coverage = c("sub", "sub", "super"),
                     Aspect = c("ZPos", "ZUnd", "Neg"))
```

actual file is much larger and outputted from old hardware. For some reason some entries have "Z" put in front of them. How do I remove from entire dataset?

I tried `df = gsub("Z", " ", df)` but it just gives me nonsense. This darn thing!

`[1] "1:3"        "c(3, 1, 2)" "c(1, 1, 2)" "c(2, 3, 1)"`

Looked on here at stackoverflow and tried stringr package but could also not get to work. Anyone know what to do?

Comment: Never call your df `data`, that shadows the builtin [`utils::data`()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/data.html)

Comment: In your regex you want '^Z', to only match leading 'Z', not inside the string

Comment: huh, okay thanks I will be sure to learn for next time!

Comment: Also I posted you a solution how to do it in stringr(/stringi) package, to avoid getting the unwanted vector of indices you got. They will be more performant than base calls.

Comment: "This darn thing" <3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach with `gsub()` is not working because that function operates on vectors, and not dataframes. However, you can `apply` `gsub()` over each column of your dataframe to get what you want:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function (x) {gsub("Z", "", x)})
```

For a `stringr` solution (that also uses `dplyr`), try:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- mutate_all(df,
                   funs(str_replace_all(., "Z", "")))
```

P.S. I recommend using `df <-` instead of `df =` in the future. Good luck!

EDIT: corrected typo - thanks @thelatemail

Comment: Thanks! Thank you for stringr solution too

Comment: What is your reason of  recommending <- instead of =?

Comment: Good question! To be perfectly fair, it's a matter of opinion, but in my experience I've found that `<-` often results in less confusion for complete beginners to programming. I think this post does a good job of covering the arguments for both: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/what-are-the-differences-between-and-in-r

Comment: `data <- lapply(data, function (x) {gsub("Z", "", x)})` won't work as intended - you want `data[] <- ...` otherwise you will get a list as output.

Comment: That's what I get for not editing this one. Thanks @thelatemail

Answer (score 1):

You may use a simple `^Z` regex in the following way:

```
df = data.frame(Mineral = c("Zfeldspar", "Zgranite", "ZSilica"),
                      Confidence = c("ZLow", "High", "Med"),
                      Coverage = c("sub", "sub", "super"),
                      Aspect = c("ZPos", "ZUnd", "Neg"))
df[] <- lapply(df, sub, pattern = '^Z',  replacement ="")
> df
   Mineral Confidence Coverage Aspect
1 feldspar        Low      sub    Pos
2  granite       High      sub    Und
3   Silica        Med    super    Neg
```

The `^Z` pattern matches the start of the string with `^` anchor, and then `Z` is matched and removed using `sub` (as there is only one possible match in the each string there is no point using `gsub`).

Comment: what is a ^7 regex?

Comment: did not know I could just use sub...this is very interesting thank you

Comment: @rockhound See [**this regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dpVnb5/1), there is also a more technical information about the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You are close. If you want to go with base `gsub`

`data$Mineral = gsub("Z", "", data$Mineral)`

You can do this for all columns. Or use a combination of `apply` strategies (see other answers!)

PS. Naming your data `data` is not a good idea. At least do `my_data`

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
as.data.frame(sapply(data, function(x) {gsub("Z", "", x)}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked how to do it in stringr(/stringi) package, to avoid getting the unwanted vector of indices you got:

```
> as.data.frame(apply(df, 2,
      function(col) stringr::str_replace_all(col, '^Z', '')))
> as.data.frame(apply(df, 2,
      function(col) stringi::stri_replace_first_regex(col, '^Z', '')))

   Mineral Confidence Coverage Aspect
1 feldspar        Low      sub    Pos
2  granite       High      sub    Und
3   Silica        Med    super    Neg
```

(where the `as.data.frame()` call is needed to turn the output array back into a df [R: apply-like function that returns a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982755/r-apply-like-function-that-returns-a-data-frame)
)

As to figuring out how exactly to call `str*_replace` function over an entire dataframe, I tried...

- the entire df:  `stri_replace_first_fixed(df, '^Z', '')`
- by rows:        `stri_replace_first_fixed(df[1,], '^Z', '')`
- **by columns**: `stri_replace_first_fixed(df[,1], '^Z', '')`

Only the last one works properly. Admittedly a design flaw on `str*_replace`, they should at minimum recognize an invalid object and produce a useful error message, instead of spewing out indices.

Comment: wow thank you. did not know I could use function(col) inside apply. That's a nice trick!

Comment: You can use any (package or user-defined) function inside apply/sapply/lapply. Here I passed in an anonymous function I defined which runs the relevant str* function on a column. I called the function argument `col` but you can call it whatever you want.

Comment: As to figuring out how exactly to call str*_replace function on a dataframe, I tried the entire df: `stri_replace_first_fixed(df, '^Z', '')` by rows: `stri_replace_first_fixed(df[1,], '^Z', '')  and by columns: `stri_replace_first_fixed(df[,1], '^Z', '')`