# Apply a function returning a data frame to each row in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame `d` and a function `f` that takes each row of the data frame to return a data frame:

```
d <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(11,22,33))

f <- function(row){
...
return(df)
}
```

Now, I want to apply `f` to `d` (to avoid looping through `f(d[k,]` of course).
`apply` can´t work and putting the rows of `d` in a list and using `lapply` failed.
What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R: apply-like function that returns a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982755/r-apply-like-function-that-returns-a-data-frame)

Comment: `apply(d, 1, f)` doesn't work? How about `lapply(asplit(d, 1), f)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah No, I get "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" despite `f` working fine for all rows (`d[k,]`) seperately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown what you have in `f` but based on comments it is written for dataframes, so this should work :

```
lapply(split(d, seq_len(nrow(d))), f)
```

`split` divides every row of `d` in 1 row-dataframe and using `lapply` we apply function `f` on each row.

You can also use `by` :

```
by(d, seq_len(nrow(d)), f)
```