# In dplyr using quasiquotation, not seeing column name in spliced function call

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

Example:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(a = c(10, 10, 10, 20, 20),
             b = c(1, 2, 10, 2, 4))

## produces desired result:
df %>%
    group_by(a) %>%
    summarize(mn = mean(b), md = median(b))

stats <- function(x){
    list(mn = mean(x), md = median(x)) }

## object 'b' not found:
df %>%
    group_by(a) %>%
    summarize(!!! stats(b))
```

The call `stats(b)` does not see column `b`. What is the simplest solution that does not involve changing the `stats` function?

R version 3.4.3, dplyr version 0.7.2

Comment: If you are attempting to summarize so that you have a mean column and median column, you could do: `summarize(mn = stats(b)[['mn']], md = stats(b)[['md']])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!!!` is meant to change the call to a function. Which means it evaluates the target in the current environment in order to change the call before running it. You seem to want to use an on object returned after a function call. But in order to use things like `b` in that function call, you need to delay the evaluation of `b` till the function is actually run. So the `!!!` and the use of `b` both need to be evaluated a different times so you run into this problem.

This is something you still should be using `do()` for, see [dplyr summarise() with multiple return values from a single function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240816/dplyr-summarise-with-multiple-return-values-from-a-single-function). For example you can do

```
df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  do(data.frame(stats(.$b)))
```

Or if you were to re-write the `stats()` function, it might look something like this

```
stats <- function(x){
  x <- enquo(x)
  quos(mn = mean(!!x), md = median(!!x)) }

df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  summarize(!!! stats(b))
```

Comment: Thanks. Your first answer is what I was seeking.